# Proving a formula for the weight distributions of a linear code

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a (linear) $[n, k]_2$ code, $(A_i)$ the weight distributions for $\mathcal C$ and $(A_i')$ the weight distributions  for $\mathcal C^\bot$. I now want to prove that:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n \pmatrix{i \\ r} \frac{A_i}{2^k} = \frac 1{2^r} \sum_{i=0}^r (-1)^i \pmatrix{n - i \\ r - i} A_i' \tag{1}$$

for $r = 0, 1, \dots, n$, and that

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n \pmatrix{i \\ r} \frac{A_i}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^r} \pmatrix{n \\ r} \tag{2} $$

in case that $r = 0, 1, \dots, d(\mathcal C^\bot) - 1$.

Now my first idea was: I already know the MacWilliams identity, and I can also use (without proof) the fact that

$$ A_k' = \frac{1}{|\mathcal C|} \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j (q - 1)^{k - j} \pmatrix{i \\ j} \pmatrix{n - i \\ k - j} A_i \tag{3} $$

for $k = 0, \dots, n$, which already "looks similar" to the formulas I want to show. So what I tried next was writing down the sum over all the $A_k'$ using the formula $(3)$, but that looked quite messy with the triple sum that was now part of the expression, and I couldn't spot an obvious way to simplify it (and I also don't know where exactly this parameter $r$ would come into play). So I'm not really sure if that is the right path (and if so, how I can continue), or if the desired formulas can be derived from something else.

Comment: Have you tried proving $(1)$ for the extreme cases $r=0$ and $r=n$? How about $(2)$ for $r=0$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I actually now managed to prove both for the general case. The idea that worked out was to take the MacWilliams equations (the general one, not even the formula I posted above) and differentiate it $r$ times with respect to $Y$ with the use of the Leibniz rule. The rest was just getting the details right afterwards; this gives $(1)$. $(2)$ then follows from the fact that for $r ≤ d(\mathcal C^\bot)-1$, the sum on the RHS of $(1)$ reduces to the very first summand because all others are $=0$. I can post the complete solution for the problem as an answer, if so desired.

Comment: Please do post your solution so that the question does not remain unanswered.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Ok, I did. If you spot any errors or believe the answer could be improved, then by all means, feel free to edit the post. (I also didn't pay overly much attention to the formatting...)

Answer (score 1):

Posting the solution here that I now got to, in case anyone is faced with the same problem.

Regarding $(1)$. For a $[n, k]$-Code, we have $|\mathcal{C}| = 2^k, |\mathcal{C}^\bot| = 2^{n-k}$ (where $\mathcal{C}^\bot$ denotes the dual code). Now MacWilliams gives us:

$W_\mathcal{C}(X, Y) = \frac 1{|\mathcal{C}^\bot|} W_{\mathcal{C}^\bot} (X + Y, X - Y)$

Setting  $ X = 1$, we get:

$W_\mathcal{C}(1, Y) = \frac 1{|\mathcal{C}^\bot|} W_{\mathcal{C}^\bot} (1 + Y, 1 - Y)$

$=> \sum_{i=0}^n A_i Y^i = \frac 1{2^{n - k}} \sum_{i=0}^n A_i' (1 + Y)^{n - i} (1 - Y)^{i} \tag{*} $

Differentiating the RHS of $(*) \space r$ times leads us to:

$\frac 1{2^{n-k}} A_i' \left(\sum_{i=0}^n (1 + Y)^{n - i} (1 -Y)^i\right)^{(r)} $

$ = \frac 1{2^{n-k}} A_i' (\sum_{i=0}^n \left((1 + Y)^{n - i} (1 -Y)^i\right)^{(r)} $

Applying the Leibniz-Rule, we get:

$ = \frac 1{2^{n-k}} A_i'  \left( \sum_{l=0}^r \pmatrix{r \\ l} (1 + Y)^{n - i} \right)^{(l)} ((1 - Y)^i)^{(r - l)}  $

$ = \frac 1{2^{n-k}} A_i'   \sum_{l=0}^r \pmatrix{r \\ l} \frac{(n - i)!}{(n - i - l)!} (1 + Y)^{n - i - l}  \frac{i!}{(i - r + l)!} (1 - Y^{i - r + l} \cdot (-1)^{r - l} $

By setting $Y = 1$ and $i := r - l, we get:

$ = \frac 1{2^{n-k}} A_i'  \sum_{l=0}^r \pmatrix{r \\ r - i} \frac{(n - i)!}{(n - i - r + i)!} (1 + Y)^{n - i - r + i}  \frac{i!}{(i - r + r - i)!} (1 - Y)^{i - r + r - i} $

which simplifies to (skipping a few easy-to-see but tedious-to-scribble-down steps here):

$ = \frac{2^k}{2^r} \sum_{i=0}^r A_i' (-1)^i \pmatrix{n  - i \\ r - i} r! \tag{4} $

which already "looks good", compared to the formula $(1)$ that we want to reach. Now if we look again at $(*)$ and differentiate the LHS aswell $r$ times, we get:

$W_\mathcal{C}^{(r)}(1, Y) = \left(\sum_{i=0}^n A_i Y^i\right)^{(r)} = \sum_{i=0}^n A_i \frac{i!}{(i-r)!} Y^{i - r} $

Setting $Y = 1$, we get:

$= \sum_{i=0}^n A_i \frac{i!}{(i - r)!} \tag{5}$

Now we differentiated both sides of $(*) \space r$ times, and set $Y = 1$ on both, hence $(4)$ and $(5)$ are equal. Therefore we get:

$\sum_{i=0}^ nA_i \frac{i!}{(i - r)!} = \frac{2^k}{2^r} \sum_{i=0}^n A_i' (-1)^i \pmatrix{n - i \\ r - i} r! $

$<=> \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{i!}{r! (i - r)!} A_i \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac 1{2^r} \sum_{i=0}^r (-1)^i \pmatrix{n - i \\ r - i} A_i'$

$<=> \sum_{i=0}^n \pmatrix{i \\ r} \frac{A_i}{2^k} = \frac 1{2^r} \sum_{i=0}^r (-1)^i \pmatrix{n - i \\ r - i} A_i'$

which is exactly the first equation we wanted to show.

For $(2)$, let's take a look at the sum that appears in the RHS of $(1)$. Now for $0 ≤ i ≤ d(\mathcal C^\bot) - 1$, the $A_i'$ are equal to $0$, and $A_0 = 1$. So if we restrict $r ≤ d(\mathcal{C}^\bot)$, then the RHS of $(1)$ simplifies to:

$ \frac 1{2^r} (-1)^0 \pmatrix{n - 0 \\ r - 0} A_0' = \frac 1{2^r} \pmatrix{n \\ r}$

Hence we get $(2)$.